# Reading tehillim for a gentile

Tags: gentiles, tehilim-psalms, memorials

A Jewish man wants to say *tehillim* for his messianic mother who died recently. The guy is a convert. Is it allowed?  What else could be done *le'ilui Nishmat*?

Comment: His mother isn't Jewish then he isn't Jewish. Is he a convert or did his mother think she was able to convert out of being Jewish? Just asking bc the question is unclear at the moment. Either way what makes you think praying for someone would not be allowed bc they aren't Jewish?

Comment: As i stated that he is Jewish, it is understood that he covered

Comment: It was not understood which is why I asked. You would improve your question by clarifying this as well as adding why you think there is an issue with saying tehillim for someone not jewish

Comment: I could hear that it's NOT allowed. If the son saying the tehilim is as if the mother was saying tehilim, and she isn't Jewish, it might be like teaching Torah to a non-Jew. But living a proper life according to Halacha is by itself an iloy neshama, and probably this would apply even to his technically unrelated mother.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's allowed.
The rule of thumb is that once your'e born a Jew you die as Jew, no matter what you did.
The source is "ישראל שחטא ישראל הוא"

Comment: Not only that, maybe in her last minutes in this world she repented. Jewish belief is that G-d's hand is always open to repentance.

Comment: The OP said the mother was a gentile

Comment: Offhand, I don't see any problem reciting Tehillim. Period. That's essentially what you're doing.

Comment: The point is she had never been jewish

Comment: "A jewish man" must have a jewish mother to be jewish

Comment: @quizhead not if he's a convert